# Making an object available to JSP request scope from Spring Web Flow

Tags: jsp, spring-webflow

I'm trying to expose an object from a flow definition in such a way that it can be retrieved later on from a JSP scriptlet like:

```
pageContext.getAttribute("myobject", pageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE)
```

I've tried putting the object in the different scopes available in Spring Web Flow with expressions like this one:

```
<set name="requestScope.myobject" value="myobj"/>
```

, with no success.

Does anyone know the proper way to achieve this goal?

Thanks.

Comment: The way you're setting/retrieving looks ok. The object `myobj` - is this already in a particular scope?

Comment: The object `myobj` is put in Spring's requestScope on a flow transition. I expected that object to be available in the JSP request scope, but it wasn't.

Comment: That should work. Are you absolutely sure that `myobj` isn't null when you set it to `requestScope.myobject`?

Comment: I have tried with a string literal (<set name="requestScope.myobject" value="'myobj'"/>, with no success. Anyway, since it seems that's the right way to do it, I'll try to find the cause of the problem elsewhere. Thanks for your help.